# Javascript displayoptional formatting in html form

Tags: html, css

I have a registration form, in which I have a field which only displays once certain rows from a drop down box has been selected.  This all works fine however I can not get the box to fit in with the current design, once the box is selected it appears out of place.  To see the box appear select the field security guarding from the sia license type field.  A link to the page can be found here: http://www.security-vacancies.net/regsitration/index.php

Any suggestions how I can get this to fit in to the current design would be much appreciated.

```
<p>
<label for="postcode">SIA License Type</label>
<select id='sia_question' onchange='displayoptional()' select="select" name="sia_question">
    <option value='' selected="selected">Please S elect</option>
    <option value='1'>Do Not Have A License</option>
    <option value='2'>Have Appied for a License </option>
    <option value='3'>Security Guarding</option>
    <option value='4'>Door Supervision</option>
    <option value='5'>Close Protection</option>
    <option value='6'>Key Holding</option>
    <option value='7'>Public Space Surveillance</option>
    <option value='8'>Vehicle Immobilisation</option>
    <option value='9'>Cash In Transit</option>
    <option value="10">Non Frontline</option>
</select>
<div style='display:none' id='optional'>
    <span class="style204"> Please Enter an SIA License Number: <input id='sia_license' type='text' name="sia_license" value=""/></span>
</div>
</p>
```

Comment: Firstly you will get a much better response if you include some code here - as a minimum how you are adding the input ...

Comment: Thanks I just thought it would be better to see in situe, here is the code for that specific field entry:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, just style it like every other field in your code:

```
<p>
    <label for="postcode">SIA License Type</label>
    <select id='sia_question' onchange='displayoptional()' select="select" name="sia_question">
        <option value='' selected="selected">Please S elect</option>
        <option value='1'>Do Not Have A License</option>
        <option value='2'>Have Appied for a License </option>
        <option value='3'>Security Guarding</option>
        <option value='4'>Door Supervision</option>
        <option value='5'>Close Protection</option>
        <option value='6'>Key Holding</option>
        <option value='7'>Public Space Surveillance</option>
        <option value='8'>Vehicle Immobilisation</option>
        <option value='9'>Cash In Transit</option>
        <option value="10">Non Frontline</option>
    </select>
</p>
<p style='display:none' id='optional'>
    <label for="postcode">SIA License Number</label>
    <input id='sia_license' type='text' name="sia_license" value=""/>
</p>
```

And that's it, I guess.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks, and now i see where i was going wrong, much appreciated.

Comment: whew, just when I found the culprit and about to post, and then the same answer is already posted. oh well.